# Make a view next to another and at the middle of its height

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, numberpicker

I'm trying to make an `Activity` with an `NumberPicker` and a `TextView` and I want that the `textView` will be next to the `NumberPicker` and it will be at the middle of `NumberPicker` Height (the TV going to be something like "choose a number:") 
any thing I've tried didn't worked. (I even tried to put any one in a different `LinearLayout` and the two `LinearLayouts` in a `RelativeLayout` and messed with the prefences and it still didn't work)

here is what I tried:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:paddingTop="30dp"
       android:text="@string/Main"/>

    <NumberPicker
       android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
       android:layout_width="30dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView1"
       android:clickable="false"
       android:paddingTop="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally do the following for this kind of situations:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/numberPicker1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/numberPicker1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
/>
```

This way the tex view appears exactly in the middle of number picker. By the way just to remind, you should put number picker before text view if you want to try this method.

Good luck!

Comment: I needed to add some more but this helped me so i will mark it as answered.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could look into a LinearLayout with a horizontal orientation, and set gravity to center to center it's children.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:gravity="center"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/Main"/>

    <NumberPicker
       android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
       android:layout_width="30dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:clickable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```